# After Effects Expressions: getter/setter functions

Tags: expression, after-effects

I'm trying to figure out if you can write an After Effects expression that works as a setter function.  The pick whip basically works as a `get` function:

```
// vars s and c generated from the pick whip:
var s = thisComp.layer("debugger").text.sourceText;
var c = effect("my checkbox")("Checkbox");
```

However, I can't seem to `set` a value somewhere else from within that same chunk of code.

```
 // doesn't work:
 s = (c==true)?"a":"b";
```

Is there a way to set the value of a property from code somewhere else, like another layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions modify the value of their host property, and nothing else.